# Spring project with aws cognito

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use aws Cognito`s user authentication with my spring project. I configured Cognito and got a jwt token from it. When I pass the token to my api endpoint I'm getting error 401 (unauthorized).

I'm working on a ms that working in my localhost.

I saw a few examples and I feel like my application.properties is missing something but I'm not sure what.

My application properties :

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2_somecode
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.app1.client-id=my_app_id_in_cognito
```

My pom has the following security dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My configuration class :

```
   @Configuration
   public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
```

Tried also to change the application properties according to some [spring examples](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-cognito) :

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-id=my_app_id_in_cognito
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-name=app1
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.issuer-uri=https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_somecode
```

but then I got the following exception because I was missing the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri` settings in application.properties :

```
Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'jwtDecoderByIssuerUri' in 'OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.JwtDecoderConfiguration' not loaded because OpenID Connect Issuer URI Condition did not find issuer-uri property
    - Bean method 'jwtDecoderByJwkKeySetUri' in 'OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.JwtDecoderConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri) did not find property 'spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri'
    - Bean method 'jwtDecoderByPublicKeyValue' in 'OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.JwtDecoderConfiguration' not loaded because Public Key Value Condition did not find public-key-location property


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' in your configuration.
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](https://kevcodez.de/posts/2020-03-26-secure-spring-boot-app-with-oauth2-aws-cognito/) and tried to use the same setting in the application.properties :

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://cognito-idp.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/{POOL_ID}
```